# Open MPI stuck on an older version

Tags: raspberry-pi, version, openmpi

I'm building a Raspberry Pi cluster and am using Open MPI to do some parallel processing... I was able to get it up and running with my Raspberry Pi 3 and a few Pi 1s, but when I tried to add another Pi 3 I started getting some errors (Error: unknown option "--hnp-topo-sig")

It's possible that the problem is because the versions of mpi between both my pis are different - my first pi 3 has version 2.0.2 while the other has 1.6.5, which is odd considering I only installed it on that pi today and on the first pi about a week ago.

I've tried sudo apt-get update and upgrade, but my pi keeps telling me that everything is up to date, even though it doesn't seem like it is. So my question is this - how can I update my open mpi to a newer version so I can run my files? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you run the same distro version on both raspberry ? As far as Open MPI is concerned, all versions must be identical.

Answer (score 0):

As Gilles noted, Open MPI requires the version to be identical on all machines.

If your Linux distro is telling you that the packaged version of Open MPI is up to date, then you probably have different versions of Linux distros on your different RPi units.

You might want to try:

1. Installing the same exact Linux distro/version on all your RPi units, and/or
2. Downloading the latest Open MPI source code tarball from www.open-mpi.org and building/installing Open MPI from source on all your RPi units.  That will definitely work, but be aware that Open MPI is a large software package -- compiling it on an RPi will take quite a while.